# Post controller require post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In an article, a Post controller is created.

But in post_params, params.require requires `:post`. How this possible or What does it mean that Post controller requires :post

```
def create
  Post.create(post_params)
  redirect_to root_path
end
private
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image, :user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a way Rails Controlling mass-assigment attributes with **strong_parameters**. this approach forbids mass-assignment of a model attribute from a controller unless that attribute was white-listed

whitelisting is configured using two methos

- **require**, calling require will validate that the parameter is actually present, if not present it will throw an error
- **permit**, calling permit with list of attributes will enable those attributes to "pass through" to model during mass-assignment (this restriction disable code injection by passing unpermitted objects, hashes etc)

from your sample above

```
params.require(:post).permit(:description, :image)
```

meaning an instance of post **must exist** in params and keys/column that allowed to pass through only description and image, if your form passing other field for example :other_description and it's not listed in permit, it will not be saved

Answer (score 0):

The class name `:post` is required because the controller expects that the parameters are arranged hierarchically under their class names, as one single POST request can yield parameters pertaining to many classes. For example your post description will be available as

```
params[:post][:description]
```

In development, it's sometimes useful to inspect the parameters in the browser window. You could use this simple code:

```
<% if !Rails.env.production? %>
  <%= debug(params) %>
<% end %>
```